# What are the units of a convolution?

Tags: units, fourier-transform, integration

The convolution of $f$ and $g$ is defined as 
$
(f * g )(t) \, \stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)\, g(t - \tau) \, d\tau
$.

Let's say that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ have units of, say, meters and Hertz, respectively; and that $t$ and $\tau$ are both time. What units does the convolution $(f * g )(t)$ have?

Answer (score 4):

The only thing in the integral that has units, besides the integrand, is the measure $\mathrm{d}\tau$. So whatever the dimensions of $f$ and $g$ are, the convolution has dimensions $[f][g][t]$, since $[\tau]=[t]$.

In your example $[f]=\textsf{L}$, $[g]=\textsf{T}^{-1}$ and $[t]=\textsf{T}$, so $[f*g]=[f][g][t]=\textsf{L}$.